# What types of apples could Pat be digging up in Wonderland’s ‘The Rabbit Sends in a Little Bill’

Tags: alice-in-wonderland, lewis-carroll

When Alice’s giant arm reaches for the White Rabbit, and he goes flying into the cucumber frames, he calls upon Pat the gardener for help:

> “Pat! Pat! Where are you?” And then a voice she [Alice] had never heard before. “Sure then I’m here! Digging for apples, yer honour!”

So what could Pat’s apples be in terms of actual plants that Carroll may have had in mind? (It must be remembered that Carroll wrote in his Diaries that he had studied Natural Botany - Diaries, Vol. 2, p. 89; that he owned dozens of books on botany and plant lore, in Lovett, Lewis Carroll Among his Books, pp. 35, 97, 137, 172, etc; and that he loved to attend flower shows throughout most of his life, for this also see The Diaries of Lewis Carroll)

Comment: if you're this interested in detailed questions about Lewis Carroll's works, you might want to find a copy of *The Annotated Alice* (link in my answer) and other Carroll-related books by Martin Gardner ...

Answer (score 7):

In Carroll's [original manuscript](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/alices-adventures-under-ground-the-original-manuscript-version-of-alices-adventures-in-wonderland), Pat (short for Patrick, presumably) is quite clearly intended as a comically ***Irish*** character. Note the repeated use of ["shure"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/47242628.pdf) (rather than sure) as a prefix to almost every statement he makes, rhotic pronunciation of "[arrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English)" (for arm), repetition of "*[yer honour](https://punch.photoshelter.com/image/I0000z83L7m5hMWQ)*", use of "*[at all at all](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151158/where-does-the-irish-idiom-at-all-at-all-come-from)*", etc.

**That being the case, the obvious thing for him to be digging out are potatoes, colloquially known as "Irish apples"**

---

[*The Annotated Alice (The Definitive Edition)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annotated_Alice#Editions) makes a similar point.

> Is this another French joke? As reader Michael Bergmann points out in
> a letter, "apple" is pomme in French, and "potato" is pomme de terre,
> or "apple of the earth." No, it is an Irish joke. **Pat is an Irish name
> and he speaks in an Irish brogue. As Everett Bleiler informs me, Irish
> apples was a nineteenth-century slang term for Irish potatoes.**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]
.

Comment: Can anyone provide a pre-1865 use of “Irish Apple as a potato” because the OED, which is excellent for this type of thing (as it is “based on historical principles)  only lists this meaning starting some 23 years later.  Here is the first entry for this meaning”1888   Science 27 Jan. 50/2   She tested nearly all of the Irish apples, and found that they had been cooked to the proper consistency save one. This particular ‘spud’ remained as hard as adamant.” If no such a pre-‘Alice’ definition exists, then the above answer would have to be considered an anachronism.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/United_States_Congressional_Serial_Set/H41HAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 - 1845

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_England_Farmer/m3NIAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22irish+apple%22+and+potato&pg=PA251&printsec=frontcover - 1833

Comment: Thanks. I now can trust this information.

Answer (score 6):

"Earth apple" (also "earth-apple") is a common euphemistic name for [Jerusalem artichokes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earthapple#English), [potatoes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earthapple#English), and [cucumbers](http://dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=*&Query=Earth+apple). The harvest of the former two is procured through digging.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that cucumbers are not dug up, but good answer nevertheless.

Comment: Could you please send in a citation for the Earth apple as potato definition.

Comment: @ferjsoto42yahoocom 'Could you please send in a citation for the Earth apple as potato definition.' I think any good unabridged English language dictionary should have it. For example *The Collaborative International Dictionary of English* v.0.48, and the *Oxford English Dictionary* both give for potato and cucumber. Wiktionary gives for potato and Jerusalem artichoke.

Comment: @ferjsoto42yahoocom "I’m pretty sure that cucumbers are not dug up, but good answer nevertheless." You may wish to read my answer all the way to the end of the second sentence. ;)

Comment: In Dutch, closely related to English, a potato is an earth-apple (aardapple).